# Oracle query not returning expected results - and different result when executed through sql linked server 

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, linked-server

I have this query

```
select * from openQuery(hades,"select to_char(T$STDT,'dd-Mon-YYYY') stdt,to_char(T$TDAT,'dd-Mon-YYYY') tdat
    ,fdG2J(T$TDAT)-fdG2J(t$stdt) diff,T$DISC 
    ,fdG2J(Sysdate) nSysD
    ,fdG2J(t$stdt) nStdt
    ,fdg2J(t$tdat) nTdat
    from BAAN.TTDSLS031020 
where T$CUNO='000022' and TRIM(T$CPGS)='1AA00'
--and fdG2J(sysdate) between fdG2J(t$stdt) and fdG2J(t$stdt) 
");
```

and returns the following result (not that the last line of the where clause is commented out).

```
STDT        TDAT        DIFF        T$DISC  NSYSD   NSTDT   NTDAT
01-Mar-12   11-Mar-12   10010       40  2455990063  2455988061  2455998071
02-Mar-12   02-Mar-12   0           50  2455990063  2455989062  2455989062
06-Mar-12   11-Mar-12   5005        60  2455990063  2455993066  2455998071
11-Mar-12   11-Mar-12   0           70  2455990063  2455998071  2455998071
18-Jul-39   01-Jan-12   2907496166  80  2455990063  2465988199  5373484365
15-Dec-85   01-Jan-12   2817496016  80  2455990063  2555988349  5373484365
```

and whe I apply the commented  between clause , the query returns no results (through sql2008 linked server)

and when I run the same query from Sql Developer (Oracle)

I get the first row

what is intriguing is:
a) why does this return different results when executed in different environments (although the server running the query is same server)?
b).why dos not between clause do not return expected result ?

Comment: `where X between Y and Y` seems like a typo

Comment: you don't provide enough details... like what does fdG2J do exactly ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  PL/SQL

Comment: @TonyP: There is no **PL** (= procedural language) in your example, only SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the indended functionality of `fdG2J()`, but in the `BETWEEN` clause, you use the same function call and argument value for both.  Therefore, both return the same value and `fdG2J(sysdate)` would need to be exactly equal rather than between the range points.

```
and fdG2J(sysdate) between fdG2J(t$stdt) and fdG2J(t$stdt) 
-- -                            ^^^^^^^^  Same as ^^^^^^^^
```

Perhaps you intended:

```
and fdG2J(sysdate) between fdG2J(t$stdt) and fdG2J(T$TDAT)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select * from openQuery(hades,"select to_char(T$STDT,'dd-Mon-YYYY') stdt,to_char(T$TDAT,'dd-Mon-YYYY') tdat
    ,fdG2J(T$TDAT)-fdG2J(t$stdt) diff,T$DISC 
    ,fdG2J(Sysdate) nSysD
    ,fdG2J(t$stdt) nStdt
    ,fdg2J(t$tdat) nTdat
    from BAAN.TTDSLS031020 
where T$CUNO='000022' and TRIM(T$CPGS)='1AA00'
and fdG2J(sysdate) between fdG2J(t$stdt) and fdG2J(T$TDAT) 
");
```